# Building Epson sane-compatible drivers on Raspbian 11

Tags: drivers, raspberry-pi, scanner

I am trying to set up my Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian 11) as scanner controller for my EPSON DS-310. I discovered EPSON offers sane-compatible Linux drivers, also as source. I downloaded them, extracted, was able to `cmake` but when trying to `make` I get the following error:

```
/home/noel/epson_linux_drivers_src/epsonscan2-6.7.63.0-1/src/CommonUtility/utils/PathUtils.cpp: In function ‘std::string ES_CMN_FUNCS::PATH::ES_GetWorkTempPath()’:
/home/noel/epson_linux_drivers_src/epsonscan2-6.7.63.0-1/src/CommonUtility/utils/PathUtils.cpp:1116:28: error: ‘EPSON_WORK_PATH’ was not declared in this scope
 1116 |    std::string work_path = EPSON_WORK_PATH;
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CommonUtility/Linux/CMakeFiles/commonutility.dir/build.make:225: CommonUtility/Linux/CMakeFiles/commonutility.dir/__/utils/PathUtils.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:262: CommonUtility/Linux/CMakeFiles/commonutility.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
```

At the same time, running `sudo sane-find-scanner` returns

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8, product=0x0159 [DS-310]) at libusb:001:005
found USB scanner (vendor=0x0424, product=0xec00) at libusb:001:003
```

so I am not even sure I need the EPSON drivers. Still scanimage or xsane can't find any scanners. Any advice on how to use my DS-310 on my Raspberry?

**UPDATE:** By adding vendor (`SYSFS{idVendor}=="04b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"`) in `/etc/udev/rules.d/55-libsane.rules` and adding the device itself in `/etc/sane.d/eponds.conf` (usb 0x 0x), I got Xsane to actually connect to my scanner and scan a page. However, it only works if Xsane is started as Admin and also color/greyscale scans are cut - lineart (black/white) scanning however works!

With each step, more problems pop up. :)